# My keyboard is set to US but using UK (@ and " switched)

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard

I installed Debian recently and the keyboard setup was set to UK. So I tried to reset it with `# dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and then did `# service keyboard-setup restart`.

After that did not work I opened up `/etc/default/keyboard` and it looked like this:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="lvl3:ralt_switch"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

My super key is also broken since I tried to workout this error this may have something to do with this.

Comment: You say @ and " are switched… but where do you expect them & where are they now? UK PC keyboards have " / 2 and @ / '. UK Mac keyboards, however, have @ / 2 and " / '. International English keyboards use the same as UK Mac, not UK PC.

Comment: it is not only " and @, more are switched. Those were just examples

Comment: Which doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Sorry I misread your response. I have an US keyboard (or a UK Mac keyboard) but it reacts as a UK pc keyboard. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards For your reference I have a US keyboard (the picture on the second paragraph) but it reacts like a UK keyboard

Comment: So it's ANSI but the system thinks it's ISO?? US & UK keyboards have distinct hardware differences, as well as linguistic.

Comment: I don't know what the system thinks it is (where can I see that). But ever since I changed to debian my keyboards config is wrong. How can I see if linux thinks it's ANSI or ISO?